# blueman manager does not start on Ubuntu 22.04 - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04, blueman

I upgraded recently from 20.04 to 22.04

When I select "Devices" in the Blueman-applet, nothing happens: the Devices panel does not appear.

I tried launching blueman-manager from terminal and I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Any suggestions how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhow, switching to x.org at login, instead of the default "ubuntu" display server, solved the issue.

BTW, it also solved Flameshot not capturing partial screenshots, zoom screen sharing not working.